# When do we use "travel to work"?

Tags: meaning

Below is from Assimil:

> I travel to work by tube.

Do we use *travel to work* when it's a long distance? Plus I thought *travel* is related to tourism.

Comment: Travel is not related to tourism, but tourism is a form of travel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually use [commute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting) to mean *travel to and from work*, it implies some distance (You don't normally *commute* if your workplace is around the corner), <strike>and it usually involves public transport</strike>*.

*Travel* isn't necessarily related to tourism. It means *to make a journey, to cover some distance, to go somewhere* (usually over a long distance).

> I travel to work (=commute) by train.
>
> He travelled (=covered) over 1,000 miles to be at the wedding.
>
> With wooden-bat baseball, the ball doesn't travel (=move) as far as it does with aluminium bats.

*Not really...

[image]

Comment: You can travel one mile/kilometre, or a thousand.

Comment: "it usually involves public transport" — Maybe if you live in a city with good transport links,  but not by definition :) The [_large_ majority of people in Ireland commute by car](https://www.cso.ie/en/releasesandpublications/ep/p-cp6ci/p6cii/p6mtw/) for instance.